# How can i do a dropdownlist empty when

Tags: javascript, sql, database, asp.net-mvc-4, drop-down-menu

I have two dropdownlists both connected to the database, one is called Distritos and the other is called Concelhos, while distritos isn´t selected concelhos are shown empty, wehn the user selects one of the words of distritos, the Concelhos are shown. This is what i have in my controller:

```
public ActionResult getcidades(int? distrito = null)
    {
        var concelho =
            Db.Concelhos.OrderBy(r => r.Nome) as IQueryable<Concelho>;

        if (distrito != null)
        {
            concelho = concelho.Where(t => t.Distritos.Id == distrito);                    
        }

        return Json(concelho.Select(r => new { Nome = r.Nome, r.Id }),  JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

This is what i have in my view:

```
     $("#Distrito").on("change", function () {
    var valor = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "@Url.Action("getcidades","PiHelper")", 
        data: {
        distrito: valor
        }
})
      .done(function (concelho) {
          var dropdown = $("#Concelho");

          dropdown.empty().focus();

          console.log(concelho, dropdown)
          for (var i = 0; i < concelho.length; i++) {
              $("<option>")
                  .attr("value", concelho[i].Id)
                  .text(concelho[i].Nome)
                  .appendTo(dropdown);
          }
      })

})
```

**IMAGE OF THE ERROR**
[Error CS1012 Too many characters in character literal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwXoo.jpg)

Comment: And what is your question?  What have you attempted to do and where are you stuck?

Comment: It might helped if you posted some code, get a better idea of what you're talking about.

Comment: Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know how put the code, but now is done.

Answer (score 0):

Return an empty string, null, or maybe a --- from your sql statement. You'll need a case statement in your sql more than likely. Without giving a code example, that's about the best I can tell you. Hope that helps.

Edit:

This is what I'm thinking, and you shouldn't have to change any sql:

```
public ActionResult getcidades(int? distrito = null)
{
    var concelho =
        Db.Concelhos.OrderBy(r => r.Nome) as IQueryable<Concelho>;

    if (distrito != null)
    {
        concelho = concelho.Where(t => t.Distritos.Id == distrito);                    
    } else {
        concelho = '---';
    }

    return Json(concelho.Select(r => new { Nome = r.Nome, r.Id }),  JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I'd start with the `else` statement I added. Then maybe do a string match on that with your ajax `done` statement.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't know how put the code, but now is done, can you help?

Comment: Edited. Does that help?

Comment: I used your code and gave me this error: "Error CS1012 Too many characters in character literal", I will put the print of the error in my question.

Comment: Oh sorry, use double quotes.

Comment: new error....."Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<School.RecruitmentManagement.Models.Concelho>'"

Answer (score 0):

This is what i came up with: (not so elegant, but works)

```js
$('#mySelect1').on('change',function(){
 if($(this).length){
   $('#mySelect2').removeClass('transparent');
    $('#mySelect2 option').removeClass('displayNone');
 }
  else{
    // nothing selected, not suppose to..    
    $('#mySelect2').addClass('transparent');
    $('#mySelect2 option').addClass('displayNone');
  }
});
```

```css
.displayNone {    
  display: none;
}

.transparent{
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<select id="mySelect1">
  <option value="1">First</option>
  <option value="2">Second</option>
  <option value="3">Third</option>
  <option value="4">Fourth</option>
</select>
 
<select id="mySelect2" class="transparent">
  <option class="displayNone" value="1">First</option> 
  <option class="displayNone" value="2">Second</option>
  <option class="displayNone" value="3">Third</option> 
  <option class="displayNone" value="4">Fourth</option>
</select>
```